# list view in column wrapped inside singlechild scrollview not scrolling flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview, singlechildscrollview

I want to achieve scrolling inside the list view in flutter.But the entire screen is scrolling here.Tried wrapping listview inside container and then in single child scroll view but that also doesnt work
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K3q0.png

```
    Scaffold(
     
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Container(
        height: double.maxFinite,
        // padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Card(
                elevation: 15,
                child: Container()
                //DashboardAppbar(emp: loggedinEmpDetails),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            selected == 0
                ? ListView(
                //  shrinkWrap: true,
                //   physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                 children: [
                   leaves == null
                       ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                       : DashboardCards(leaves!),
                   const SizedBox(
                     height: 10,
                   ),
                   for (int i = 0; i < userLeaves!.length; i++)
                     dashboardLeaveCards(
                         emp: employee![0],
                         userLeaves: userLeaves![i],
                         selected: selected,
                         leaveReasons: leaveReason),
                   const SizedBox(
                     height: 5,
                   )
                 ],
                    )
                : Column(
```

Comment: Can you include sample widget

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code-image

Comment: It will be easier if you update the snippet with minimal version that will not depend on others data

Comment: Wrap ListVIew with Expanded, Also `dashboardLeaveCards` widget is unknown, find more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: dashboardLeaveCards is a widget that return card widget

Comment: Is that big enough get screen height

Comment: no its take height of 130 px

Comment: dashboardLeaveCards with different userleaves

Comment: comment this and check if it overflows or not

Comment: that column is in the else clause

Comment: I fixed it ,it was my mistake that i didnt add tabbar view,the issue got resolved once it is added.

Answer (score 0):

Add physics and shrinkWrap to the list view

```
ListView(
  shrinkWrap:true,
  physics : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
)
```

And remove the inner SingleChildScrollView to which you added physics..

**Edit**

Instead of listview use List.generate

```dart
    Scaffold(
     
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        // padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8),
        child:  Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Card(
                elevation: 15,
                child: Container()
                //DashboardAppbar(emp: loggedinEmpDetails),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            selected == 0
                ? Expanded( 
              child:ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
                 // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                 children: [
                   leaves == null
                       ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                       : DashboardCards(leaves!),
                   const SizedBox(
                     height: 10,
                   ),
                   for (int i = 0; i < userLeaves!.length; i++)
                     dashboardLeaveCards(
                         emp: employee![0],
                         userLeaves: userLeaves![i],
                         selected: selected,
                         leaveReasons: leaveReason),
                   const SizedBox(
                     height: 5,
                   )
                 ],
                    )
                : Column(
             mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
             )
)
```

Comment: tried,but doesnt work

Comment: im using multiple widgets inside the listview

Comment: Others are in column. So you can add it directly in the column and to add a list of items use list. Generate

Comment: I have added other widgets in comment there you can add other other widgets.

Comment: i have given condition also.if selected =0 then show list view otherwise show another column widgets,so i cannot take them out

Comment: Edited answer again

Comment: tried, doesnt work

Comment: Check now please. Added your own codes and fixes to it

Comment: the whole screen is scrolling now,want only the list view to scroll

Comment: Remove SingleChildScrollView and remove physics from listview. Edited the answer too

Comment: overflow pixel issue

Comment: Wrap the listview with an expanded widget

Comment: then also overflow issue

Comment: Which means it has no space for the listview to display

Comment: list view contains leavecards of length 10 if i add singlechild scrollview initially no overflow issue but whole screen scrolls

Comment: In leave cards if you have listview add shrinkwrap true, and if you have a column add mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min

Comment: leave cards returns the card widget inside which is a row

Comment: Thats fine. But it should work

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap with multiple scrollable widget, just wrap `ListView` with `Expanded` widget, and follow this widget structure.

```dart
body: Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Card(elevation: 15, child: Container()
          //DashboardAppbar(emp: loggedinEmpDetails),
          ),
    ),
    const SizedBox(
      height: 10,
    ),
    selected == 0
        ? Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                //  leaves == null
                //      ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                //      : DashboardCards(leaves!),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                  ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        : SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [],
            ),
          )
  ],
),
);
```

Comment: did you remove others scollable widget?

Comment: yes i removed the other scrollable widgets

Comment: Ok try current snippet

Comment: ovrflow pixel issue

Comment: Can you share an image or overflow